# SIEM-like tool for pcaps

Tags: siem, pcap

Is there any tool that accepts a packet capture file as input and displays all the network traffic in a similar way to how a SIEM displays log information? I'm looking for a summary of the ports and IPs to get a good overview of a packet capture.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "is there a product/service that does X?" are off-topic as the answers might not end. And this is a networking question, not a security question (despite the comparison to a SIEM)

Comment: Is there a good place on the internet to ask questions about specific tools like the one mentioned here?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great platforms in this arena, the first I ever heard of, SecurityOnion. It's still great after all these years

There are also other platforms such as [Malcom](https://github.com/cisagov/Malcolm) and [VAST](https://github.com/tenzir/vast) that have different perspectives.